# Extracting Docker Container to an bootable hdd disk

Tags: linux, docker

I have an docker container. I would like to extract the filesystem and put it on a ssd. At the end I want to put the ssd into another computer, so the computer can boot from the ssd.

At the moment I'm creating my docker container.
Extracting the filesystem with "docker export"
partitioning and creating my ssd. Then I copy the extracted filesystem, adjust the /etc/fstab as well as changing the /etc/hostname.

Here is the problem: When I start the ssd in my other computer, grub loads fine. But while booting linux, it just stops somewhere in the boot process. Right after adding the swap partition, it doesn't do anything else. (No error appears).

What can I add to my container so the extracted filesystem contains everything for an successful start?

Comment: Have you considered booting one of the slimmed down OSes designed to run Docker? Boot2docker, Coreos, RancherOs, Atomic.....

Comment: Yes I have thought about it. I was hopping not have this extra layer. It makes it easier for the people who work on the target machine, if there is no docker. They need full access to sound, graphics, gps, etc...

Comment: Docker can be run with host networking and/or with access to devices by running in privileged mode. https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-linux-capabilities-and-lxc-configuration Not entirely clear to me why you want to use docker, yet not use it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Docker containers (and images) do not contain a boot partition, only a root partition.

Comment: Yes of course. I added a root partition. I used to do every thing with 'debootstrap' and then use 'chroot' and install everything else with 'apt-get' and do all the configuration. And then deployed it on the ssd. This works. I was hoping to replace debootstrap and chroot with a docker container. The system also kind of boots. But it just seems to stop booting at some point without error. I wonder if some services are missing. I don't really know where to start looking.